# Function f that preserves difference in distribution

Tags: probability, integration, probability-theory, measure-theory

Suppose we have two random vectors $X: \Omega \to \mathbb{R}^n$ and $\tilde X: \Omega \to \mathbb{R}^n$ that are different in distribution and a function $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$.

What are conditions on $f$ that guarantee that $f(X) \neq f(\tilde X)$ in distribution?

My thoughts until now: Since $X \neq \tilde X$ in distribution, there is a continuous and bounded function $g: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ such that
$$ \int g(X) \; dP \neq \int g(\tilde X) \; dP $$

If $f$ had a continuous inverse, then $g\circ f^{-1}: \mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}$ would be continuous and bounded and clearly would serve as a *certificate* that $f(X) \neq f(\tilde X)$.

Hence, the above is a sufficient condition. Are there weaker conditions?